# How can I set proxyTimeout in express-gateway?

Tags: node.js, timeout, express-gateway

> Where exactly do I put proxyTimeout in gateway.config.yml?

Comment: did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set timeout for proxy in pipelines:

```
pipelines:
  - name: default
    apiEndpoints:
      - test
    policies:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: testService
              proxyTimeout: 6000
```